# Is $C[a,b]$ separable space?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Is $C[a,b]$ separable space with norm $||f||=\int_{a}^{b}\left | f(x) \right |dx$? with norm $||f||=(\int_{a}^{b} f(x)^{2}dx)^{1/2}$?

I though with linear combinations of functions but I am confused. Thanks.

Comment: Are you aware that it is separable with the sup-norm?

Comment: yes, separable with sup.

Comment: For future reference, avoid starting posts with *greetings*.

Answer (score 0):

The space $C[a,b]$ is separable with the sup-norm.  This means that there is a countable set $\{f_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ such that for each $f\in C[a,b]$ and $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\|f_n-f\|_\infty<\varepsilon$.  Then we have
$$ \|f_n-f\|_1=\int_a^b|f_n-f|\leq (b-a)\|f_n-f\|_\infty<(b-a)\varepsilon,$$
hence is it separable with the $L^1$ norm.  The proof for the $L^2$ norm is similar.