# $C[a,b]$ separablity

Tags: functional-analysis

$C[a,b]$ with sup-norm is separable ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1943107/is-ca-b-separable-space)) while $C_b(\mathbb{R})$ is not.

Why cannot [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/254652) be applied on $C[a,b]$?

Comment: How many integers are there in the interval $[a,b]$?

Comment: finite number of course. but does the function necessarily have to be at the integers?

Comment: @user861252 You could choose some countable subset of $[a,b]$. But this countable subset will have an accumulation point, and the closer you get to the accumulation point, the wilder the function must oscillate. But a continuous function on a compact interval is uniformly continuous; infinite oscillation is not possible.